# How to protect global variables (window) from being overwritten

Tags: javascript, typescript, security

I am currently working on a project where security is very important. By default, all global variables/properties like `Promise` or even `crypto` can be overwritten.

Is there a way to protect them from being overwritten?

Example:

```
window.crypto.getRandomValues = () => { return [1] }

window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] // 1
```

My first thought was to use `Object.freeze()` to lock the object, but one can simply overwrite the `Object.freeze` method so it does nothing.

We are already very selective of the dependencies we use, but I would still like to make sure that those variables can not be overwritten. Or at least detect if they were overwritten.

Comment: It's the user's own browser - in the end, they can run whatever code they want, and they may monkeypatch whatever they want as well.

Comment: maybe only eslint rule https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-global-assign

Comment: If the user wants to do that himself I can live with it. But I want to prevent other libraries to interfere with mine. So if locking the global variables is not possible, is there a way to "sandbox" the different dependencies? I read the proposal about `realms`. I think this would be what I'm looking for, but it's not ready yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: All this is just a rough outline, not thoroughly tested. I'm sure there are more problems to solve.

---

[freezing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the window-object is no option, this would just cause problems, but maybe Objects like `window.crypto`?

But you can re-define properties to be no longer changeable, even on the window-object

```
function freezeProp(target, propertyName) {
  const { value, get = () => value, set = () => void 0, ...desc } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyName);
  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyName, { ...desc, get, set, configurable: false });
}

freezeProp(window, "crypto");
```

But these methods only work out if you can ensure that you are the first script to run.

Detecting if some methods have been changed is also just possible if you have a reference to them; and we're back at being the first script to run.

---

But if you're not sure wether the global scope has been spoiled, why not get a fresh window-object?

```
window.crypto.getRandomValues = () => {
  return [1]
};

const secure = (() => {
  let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  const contentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  return contentWindow;
})();

var a = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1));
console.log(a);

var b = secure.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1));
console.log(b);
```

Comment: You came to the same conclusion as I. You have to ensure to be the *first* to freeze/lock objects, before someone else can overwrite anything. Your solution seems to work for crypto, but for example "Proxy" and "Promise" can still be overwritten. My initial thought would be to create `const safeProxy = Proxy` and lock it's properties, so you can always rely on safeProxy being there and in it's original form. BTW, your last approach with the iframe doesn't work, because one can simply overwrite the `document.createElement` function :).